# how to get the dimensions of the form (m,n) from (m,)

Tags: python

I have done the following:
 `y = df['C']` where `df` is a dataframe. 
  `y.shape` is returning `(m,)` but I want it to be of the form `(m,1)` i.e. of the form `(m,n)`.

How can I do this?
I am using numpy library. I tried this: `y = df.C.values`. but the result is the same.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `(m,)` **is** `(m,1)` right? I.e. a matrix with one column is just a column vector, and its shape can be represented by a tuple with only one element.

Comment: You need a simply `reshape`

Comment: @yatu Thanks it worked.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are accessing a column of the DataFrame, you are taking a 1D vector of size #rows. If you want to have a second dimension 1 for every element, such that instead of `[1, 2, 3, 4]` you want `[[1], [2], [3], [4]]`, cast it to a NumPy ndarray with `.values` attribute and then reshape it to size `(-1, 1)`.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4], columns=['C'])
col_c_1 = df['C'].values         # Shape (4,)
col_c_2 = col_c_1.reshape(-1, 1) # Shape (4, 1)
```

With `-1` you are saying to fill the first dimension size automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You only need a reshape.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]], columns=['A','B'])
print(df['B'].shape)
new_B=df.B.values.reshape((len(df),1))
print(new_B.shape)
```

And you get this:

```
(3,)
(3, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The results are obvious as (m,1) and (m,) are same because a one columned vector can be represented with a single dimension as the output you are getting.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> s=np.array(a)
>>> s
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> s.shape
(5,)
```